# Webpage Title user name

Tags: php, sql, title

I want to put the name of the loggedin user as the title of the page. But I've no idea how to do it. I've tried several ways but each one show a parse error. here is my php code for logging in the user and then showing his details.

```
<?php

                //if the login session does not exist therefore meaning the user is not logged in
                if(strcmp($_SESSION['uid'],"") == 0){
                    //display and error message
                    echo "<center>You need to be logged in to user this feature!</center>";
                }else{
                    //otherwise continue the page

                    //this is out update script which should be used in each page to update the users online time
                    $time = date('U')+50;
                    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `employer` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
                    $display_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employer WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
                    echo "<table id='pageTable'><tbody><th>Your Details</th>";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display_query)){
                        echo "<tr><td>Name&#58;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row['name']."</td><tr>";
                        $titlename = $row['name'];
                        echo "<tr><td>E&#45;Mail ID&#58;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row['email']."</td><tr>";
                        echo "<tr><td>Contact No&#46;&#58;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row['contact']."</td><tr>";
                        echo "<tr><td>Company&#58;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row['company']."</td><tr>";
                        echo "<tr><td>Designation&#58;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row['designation']."</td><tr>";
                    }

                    echo "</tbody>";
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "<table><tr><td>";
                    echo '<div class="button"><a href="functions/logout.php">Logout</a></td></tr></table>';


                //make sure you close the check if they are online
                }

            ?>
```

Comment: no error. The title of the page appears blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code to display loginname as title

```
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'document.title = \''.$row['name'].'\'';
 echo '</script>'
```

Comment: Eugh. Don't do things with JavaScript when you can do them with HTML. And don't write HTML 3.2.

Comment: i think, somehow php code is in middle of html, so i used java script to change title of page

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you properly markup your page: doctype, html-head-body etc. You can do that and while the body is still 'open', state your php code by simply starting with `<?php` followed by your script.

Then, the relevant part of your loginname-as-title code:

```
<head>
  <title><?php echo $loginName ?></title><!-- thanks to Berry Langerak for noting 'echo' was missing -->
</head>
<body>
<?php
```

where `$loginName` is of course your var for the login ID you want to show.

Comment: Just `$loginName` isn't going to show anything. Use `echo` or `print` to show it. Also, do some escaping of the output, so it's not sensitive to XSS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the data you want before you output the `<head>` section of the page, then include a [`<title>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2) element in it.

```
<title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($myTitle); ?></title>
```